# Pros and cons of building apps with proprietary database systems

Tags: 4d-database

I've been interested in [4D SAS](http://4d.com)' database product for a long time, though have barely touched it in eons.

In considering what tools to use for application development, especially one that will require a database component, what should be looked for when considering open-source tools like MySQL and PostgreSQL vs proprietary solutions like 4D or Pervasive SQL?

What good (and bad!) experiences has the SO community had with various DB tools like 4D, Pervasive, FilemakerPro, etc?

Any bad experiences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4D is a MacOS/Windows only cross-platform, proprietary database system with both stand-alone and Client-Server varieties. You would do well to compare it to Alphafive.com software which is Windows only. I've worked with it for 17 years and it has served me and my department very well. Off the top of my head ...

Pros:

1. Interface & code are closely tied to the data engine which makes development of rich, cross-platform user interfaces very fast and easy.
2. Proprietary relational data engine runs natively on both platforms, along with native client interfaces (but requires licenses for multi-users). Auto-relations are helpful (but sometimes get in the way).
3. Can access external systems via SOAP and ODBC and SQL drivers (limited).
4. Can access 4D from external systems via SOAP or http requests & web pages.
5. Native procedural programming language based on Pascal and is EASY to learn.
6. Excellent tool for small to mid-sized departments.
7. Latest version accepts subset of SQL commands AND original data access, so it's backward compatibility record has been very good.
8. Security is EASY in 4D.
9. You can build solutions to deploy through a variety of means, and are not limited by whether or not MS Access is installed.

Cons:

1. Interface & code are closely tied to the data engine which can lead to limited use of abstraction and "black-box" coding unless you make it a goal of your development.
2. Compiles to one monolithic structure file forcing restart for single fixes.
3. Language is still only procedural--making it harder for object-oriented programmers to accept.  Every method requires separate "file" in 4D so you can't include more then one function or procedure in a single routine -- it will take some getting used to it.
4. While company appears to be in good shape, growing and developing, you simply never know as they keep their condition to themselves.
5. Company has never really marketed itself--trusting in its developer base to spread the word and grow the product through site deployments and product upgrades. Web site is clearly useful only to developers who already use the product -- it simply fails to attract new users.
6. Product upgrades have always seemed to focus on how the tool is better for the DEVELOPERS rather than for the CUSTOMERS of those developers.
7. SQL lacks views, compound indexes, and other common SQL features.
8. When a user requests a report of specific columns of data, I often have to  write yet another program just to provide that specific data -- I can't always just query the data and generate a text file.
9. Does not handle new OS versions with nearly the ease of web browser based applications.  Older version is broken on Mac OS 10.6, and newest version requires the latest Mac OS 10.6.  No version is certified yet on Windows 7.

I've been nearly a year at learning ASP.NET and a few weeks at Ruby on Rails. While SQL data stores are EASY, user interface is HARD -- but worth it when your application still functions through OS upgrades. You can always use an older browser if the latest version breaks something.

I'd recommend you consider either of those, depending on how much funds you have available to implement the project--Rails being the cheaper of the two.  Then, ANY system with a web browser can access the data, and you can fix interface pages on the fly as needed rather than taking the whole system down a few minutes for a single, simple update.  Those skills might be more marketable in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Difficult to make a relevant list of Pros and Cons without a context.

My advice would be the following: when making the decision of using a proprietary database, make sure that this decision is based on strong facts and not merely a technical interest for an exotic tool. Put into the balance the benefits for using the proprietary database and the advantages of a non-proprietary solution.

The answer is different from system to system.

A prerequisite is that your system is well identified, with a clear scope, a quite predictable evolution, so that the results of your analysis will be robust. Then, if your proprietary solution brings a real benefit for your system, that you are comfortable with the support and that you can afford the overall cost, you should be a good candidate for the proprietary solution.

Answer (score 2):

I will only say one thing.. Watch the "actual" cost of your decision.. Most proprietary database systems are Windows only.. or sometimes Mac/Windows only.

This means that along with paying quite a bit of money for the database system, you must also pay a good amount of money on a Server operating system to run it...

Also, compare the database system with current open source solutions. Is it really worth it? After moving from Microsoft Sql Server(which has a free edition, but anyway) to PostgreSQL I was blew away that people pay so much for SQL Server.. I mean, Postgres to me is a lot more clean, and most of it works exactly how you'd expect(unlike in certain SQL server syntaxes) and it has more features built into it(programming stored procs in Ruby anyone?)

So basically, compared the proprietary with the open source software and decide upon which one to take by total pricing(including OS) and feature set..

Answer (score 1):

- Pro of zeroing in on any DB: it's got good non-portable features that help you get things done
- Con of zeroing in on any DB: sometimes a different DB is appropriate (for example running your tests with in-memory SQLite instances), but that option is now closed
- Con of a proprietary commercial DB: if you need many instances, licensing costs can kill you

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following questions:

- How easy (or difficult) is it to make changes in maintenance?  Applications are likely to spend far more time in maintenance than they do in development, so if changes are hard, long-term pain is guaranteed.
- What is the quality of support?  A system that is well-documented, proprietary or otherwise, is going to be easier to work with.
- How large (or small) is the user community?  Systems with larger user communities mean more people to ask for assistance if and when things go wrong.
- How robust are the import/export capabilities of this proprietary database system?

I found the last point particularly useful at my first full-time job.  Our client was using CA-Ingres, and no one at the company knew it well enough to write queries to validate the data.  So I came up with the idea of exporting the data from Ingres and importing it into MS SQL Server (which I knew from a brief stint at Sybase Professional Services) so we could write our validation queries there.  If it had been really hard to export data from Ingres, my idea wouldn't have been an option at all.

Answer (score 1):

From 4D's webpage, I gather that we are looking at a complete development+deployment environment, not a standalone database as such. So the alternatives you could be looking at include stuff like django, ruby-on-rails, hibernate and others. The real question, of course, is if the proprietary system can save you enough money doing the product lifetime to justify the costs of the product. And that would depend on the type of human resources you have available.

Answer (score 1):

4D is a good option for vertial applications. I have worked for a company which used 4D to build a medical records and billing application for general practitioners and specialists. The rapid design and deployment features of 4D enabled the application to quickly move with market desires and legislated changes to medical record storage.The environment itself was not cutting edge, but it was integrated, cross platform and very productive.

If you are entering a market with high vendor lock-in and a high barrier to entry, then I think proprietory integrated development environments are a good option.

Comment: John is talking about JonokeMed I believe

Answer (score 1):

At various points in my career, I've used and gotten very good at FileMaker Pro, FoxPro, 4D, and a few other commercial products. Now I mainly use PHP/MySQL, and haven't used the latest versions of any of the products.

I've always liked FileMaker because most people who can use a computer can pick up FileMaker and design their own systems. They don't have to know programming or database design. But, you can "program" FileMaker, put a web front end on it, or do other more sophisticated setups if you need to. Many times I was "handed" a system created in FileMaker by a non-technical person that needed to be made into a full fledged data management system. The good part was that all the "specs" and data flow were already designed into a system. The prototype was already created!

4D and FoxPro I always found required a certain amount of extra programming and/or database knowledge to really do anything with. 4D & FileMaker are really complete self-contained systems, not just database systems. Although they all have the ability to hook into other backend databases systems (i.e. MySQL, Oracle), that is not their strong point.

On the downside, doing more complex, dynamic systems can be difficult in 4D and Filemaker due to everything being tightly coupled. Because of their cost, you really would want to create multiple systems with them. Which means you need to really "buy into them" to get your money's worth.

Answer (score 1):

The key concept is always adherence to standards: if you plan to use 4D's custom and / or special designed functions (but the discussion could be far more general, and cover any other free or commercial tool in the wild), well, just use it and take your advantage.

Not surprisingly, that's why huge DB systems like Oracle or IBM's DB2 in the past were wide accepted for specific business areas, as commercial transactions, for instance.

The other main reason to adopt a very closed solution is the legacy support. One of the products you cited (Pervasive SQL) acted as a no-effort port for BTrieve-based applications in late 90s, and it gained popularity thanks to the huge BTrieve community all over the planet.

Finally, last but not least, you should evaluate the TCO (Total Cost of Ownership) not only in terms of license price (single seat, network environment, site licenses and so on), but also for what concerns tech support, updates and availability for your platform. Many business units I know have been obliged to change their base OS for DB related problems.

Tip: add a bonus for custom solution that are proven or supported for usage in virtualized environments, if you aren't in seek for extreme performances. It will save more than a head ache for your DB manager.

In all other cases, rely on opensource/freesoftware DBs. MySql and Postgres for big projects, SQLite for single app persistence layer. Fairly standard and very good (community) support. Good value for no price.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have any experiences with the proprietary database products you listed: 4D, Pervasive, FilemakerPro.

I'd be interested in knowing what those products offer that make them more attractive to you than the open source alternatives, you listed: MySQL and PostgreSQL.

I'd be interested in what makes those more attractive to you than the much more popular proprietary alternatives: Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, etc.

Without you providing more specifics, it's hard to advise you.

I personally feel safer using a widely used open source solution than a narrowly used closed source solution.   The more widely used, the more battle-tested it's likely to be.   The more open, the more control over my own destiny I have in case I do encounter some bug.

I have reported bugs to open source projects and gotten a quick fix.  I have reported bugs to companies that make for-profit proprietary software and have gotten nothing.

Comment: it's not so much that other alternative aren't good - I'm just trying to find out why I'd pick one over another :)